# Minio behind Traefik error - Gateway Timeout

Tags: traefik, minio

I am trying to run Minio behind a Traefik proxy but getting a Gateway Timeout error.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

x-minio-common: &minio-common
  image: quay.io/minio/minio:latest
  command: 
    - server
    - --console-address
    - ":9001"
    - /data  
  networks:
    - appnet
  environment:
    - MINIO_ROOT_USER=admin
    - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MINIO_DOMAIN=minio.mydomain.com
    - MINIO_SERVER_URL=https://minio.mydomain.com
    - MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL=https://minio-console.mydomain.com
  labels:
    - traefik.enable=true
    - traefik.docker.network=appnet
    - traefik.http.routers.minio.rule=Host(`minio.mydomain.com`)
    - "traefik.http.routers.minio.entrypoints=websecure"
    - "traefik.http.routers.minio.tls=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.minio.tls.certresolver=leresolver"    
    - traefik.http.routers.minio.service=minio
    - traefik.http.services.minio.loadbalancer.server.port=9000

    - traefik.http.routers.minio-console.rule=Host(`minio-console.mydomain.com`)
    - "traefik.http.routers.minio-console.entrypoints=websecure"
    - "traefik.http.routers.minio-console.tls=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.minio-console.tls.certresolver=leresolver"    
    - traefik.http.routers.minio-console.service=minio-console
    - traefik.http.services.minio-console.loadbalancer.server.port=9001
services:
  minio1:
    <<: *minio-common
    hostname: minio1
    container_name: minio1
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /mnt/disk1
        target: /data

networks:
  appnet:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to set the network in the traefik container.